# How to update user iOS app with Apple Enterprise account

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, iphone, xcode

I have an Enterprise Apple Account. I want to update the user app without any notification.

Let me explain my requirement -

I have one iOS native app (Say app1). I have my own cocoa-pods library (Say lib1). I have integrated my own cocoa-pods library lib1 to native app app1. there is no issue. I have integrated and know the basic procedure to integrate this.

Now my requirement is that if I change something in my cocoa-pod library lib1, then it should be automatically reflect to Native iOS app app1 without sharing new build with users.

I don't want to run the command pod install or pod update and then share new ipa with users or enterprise link.

Comment: It doesn't work that way. If you change some source code then you need to rebuild the binary and distribute a new version. If you are using an MDM to manage your devices (which you should be) then it can push the version to your devices. If you aren't then the users will need to manually install the new build.

Comment: I need to reach this requirement. Could you please tell me about MDM ?

Comment: There are lots of MDM servers available from vendors like JAMF, Cisco Meraki, VMWare....

Comment: Thanks, I will explore about this. thanks a lot for your suggestions.